# I get "yarn: error: no such option: -p" when try run tests

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

When I attempt to run anchor tests through `anchor test` I get the following error:

```
warning: `hello` (lib) generated 1 warning (run `cargo fix --lib -p hello` to apply 1 suggestion)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 5m 30s

Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

Running test suite: "/home/user/hello/Anchor.toml"

Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: -p
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you using?

Did you install `yarn` using [corepack](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)?

Comment: My node version is `v18.19.0`. No I installed it using `npm`.